# Skipping duplicated rolled up rows where data is NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to create a report for an organization hierarchy by positions. The hierarchy has 4 levels, the Position is always the last leaf, but the path is not necessarily 4 levels deep.

For example:

Company > position

Company > Section > Department > position

I want to get the number of personnel.

```
declare @hierarchy table
(
    Company nvarchar(50),
    Section nvarchar(50),
    Department nvarchar(50),
    Unit nvarchar(50),
    Position nvarchar(50),
    Person nvarchar(50)
)

insert into @hierarchy values
('WD', 'Weapons', 'IT', 'officer', null, 'Wile E.'),
('ACME', 'Weapons', 'IT', 'Network', 'engineer', 'Brain'),
('ACME', 'Weapons', 'IT', 'Network', 'support', 'Pinky'),
('ACME', 'Weapons', 'IT', 'officer', null, 'Bugs'),
('ACME', 'Weapons', 'IT', 'officer', null, 'Elmer'),
('ACME', 'Weapons', 'IT', 'officer', null, 'Daffy'),
('ACME', 'Weapons', 'tech', null, null, 'Sylverster'),
('ACME', 'Anvils', 'officer', null, null, 'Road')

select Company, Section, Department, Unit, Position, count(Person) from @hierarchy
group by rollup(Company, Section, Department, Unit, Position)
```

In the above example, I get the same 3 rows for WD (WD, Anvils, officer, NULL, NULL), where one would be enough, because Unit and Position are not applicable.

However, if I put a `distinct` in the query, I get a seemingly good result

```
select distinct Company, Section, Department, Unit, Position, count(Person) from @hierarchy
group by rollup(Company, Section, Department, Unit, Position)
```

What I don't know is if this is just some hack and I got lucky, or if it's a correct approach for this problem?

Comment: please, add expecting result

Comment: @backs:if you run the query user provided there are duplicate rows,user doesn't want those duplicate

Comment: Use `GROUP BY` for each column then use `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 1):

Let's add [`GROUPING`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178544(v=sql.105).aspx) columns for every level:

```
SELECT 
    Company, 
    Section, 
    Department, 
    Unit, 
    Position, 
    GROUPING(Company) as Company, 
    GROUPING(Section) AS Section, 
    GROUPING(Department) AS Department,
    GROUPING(Unit) AS Unit,
    GROUPING(Position) AS Position,
    COUNT(*)
from @hierarchy
group by ROLLUP(Company, Section, Department, Unit, Position)
```

And look at your duplicate values:

```
Company    Section    Department Unit       Position   Company Section Department Unit Position 
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------- ------- ---------- ---- -------- -----------
ACME       Anvils     officer    NULL       NULL       0       0       0          0    0        1
ACME       Anvils     officer    NULL       NULL       0       0       0          0    1        1
ACME       Anvils     officer    NULL       NULL       0       0       0          1    1        1
ACME       Anvils     NULL       NULL       NULL       0       0       1          1    1        1
ACME       Weapons    IT         Network    engineer   0       0       0          0    0        1
ACME       Weapons    IT         Network    support    0       0       0          0    0        1
ACME       Weapons    IT         Network    NULL       0       0       0          0    1        2
ACME       Weapons    IT         officer    NULL       0       0       0          0    0        3
ACME       Weapons    IT         officer    NULL       0       0       0          0    1        3
ACME       Weapons    IT         NULL       NULL       0       0       0          1    1        5
ACME       Weapons    tech       NULL       NULL       0       0       0          0    0        1
ACME       Weapons    tech       NULL       NULL       0       0       0          0    1        1
ACME       Weapons    tech       NULL       NULL       0       0       0          1    1        1
ACME       Weapons    NULL       NULL       NULL       0       0       1          1    1        6
ACME       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       0       1       1          1    1        7
WD         Weapons    IT         officer    NULL       0       0       0          0    0        1
WD         Weapons    IT         officer    NULL       0       0       0          0    1        1
WD         Weapons    IT         NULL       NULL       0       0       0          1    1        1
WD         Weapons    NULL       NULL       NULL       0       0       1          1    1        1
WD         NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       0       1       1          1    1        1
NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL       1       1       1          1    1        8
```

(ACME,Anvils,officer) repeats 3 times, but every time it's a new level of grouping: by Department, by Department and Unit, by Department, Unit and Position. It' because we use all columns in group by. But values in Unit and Position are `NULL`.

So, you can add `DISTINCT` to your query to get unique results by your columns - it's correct.

Comment: @romeozor can you accept my answer or I need to add some comments?